# Store and Sync local Data using Breezejs and MVC Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, local-storage, breeze, asp.net-web-api

I want to use breezejs api for storing data in local storage (indexdb or websql) and also want to sync local data with sql server.

But I am failed to achieve this and also not able to find sample app of this type of application using breezejs, knockout and mvc api.

My requirement is:

1) If internet is available, the data will come from sql server by using mvc web api.

2) If internet is shutdown, the application will retrieve data from cached local storage (indexdb or websql).

3) As soon as internet is on, the local data will sync to sql server.

Please let me know Can I achieve this requirement by using breezejs api or not?

If yes, please provide me some and links and sample.

If no, what other can we use for achieving this type of requirement?

Thanks.

Please help me to meet this requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, but I would suggest simply using localstorage.  Basically, every time you read from the server or save to the server, you export the entities and save that to local storage.  THen, when you need to read in the data, if the server is unreachable, you read the data from localstorage and use importentities to get it into the manager and then query locally.

```
function getData() {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery
               .from("{YourAPI}");

    manager.executeQuery.then(saveLocallyAndReturnPromise)
        .fail(tryLocalRestoreAndReturnPromise)

    // If query was successful remotely, then save the data in case connection 
    // is lost
    function saveLocallyAndReturnPromise(data) {
        // Should add error handling here.  This code
        // assumes tis local processing will be successful.
        var cacheData = manager.exportEntities()
        window.localStorage.setItem('savedCache',cacheData);

        // return queried data as a promise so that this detour is
        // transparent to viewmodel
        return Q(data);
    }
    function tryLocalRestoreAndReturnPromise(error) {
        // Assume any error just means the server is inaccessible.
        // Simplified for example, but more robust error handling is
        // warranted
        var cacheData = window.localStorage.getItem('savedCache');
        // NOTE: should handle empty saved cache here by throwing error;
        manager.importEntities(cacheData); // restore saved cache
        var query = query.using(breeze.FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache);
        return manager.executeQuery(query); // this is a promise
    }
}
```

This is a code skeleton for simplicity.  You should check catch and handle errors, add an isConnected function to determine connectivity, etc.

If you are doing editing locally, there are a few more hoops to jump through.  Every time you make a change to the cache, you will need to export either the whole cache or the changes (probably depending on the size of the cache).  When there is a connection, you will need to test for local changes first and, if found, save them to the server before requerying the server.  In addition, any schema changes made while offline complicate matters tremendously, so be aware of that.

Hope this helps.  A robust implementation is a bit more complex, but this should give you a starting point.

Comment: Is this line is compulsory. window.localStorage.setItem('savedCache',data); Where Breezejs saves its cached data? Do we explicitly need to save in local storage?

Comment: No.  Breeze saves its cache separately.  That line ensures that when you start the app again, if there is no connection to the server, you can work with the most-recent data from the server.  If you are do not close the tab or browser, you should not need to save to the local storage and can just work from the cache.  My experience has been that the end user _always_ wants the data there when they fire up the web page, whether there is a connection to the server or not.